# Rotated $\ltimes$ symbol

Tags: rotating

I'd like to use a rotated version of `$\ltimes$` where the vertical line is at the top, and another where the vertical line is at the bottom. I tried using `\rotatebox` with `graphicx`, but it puts the symbol either too high or too low. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can rotate with respect to the center of the glyph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\btimes}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\ltimes$}}}
\newcommand{\utimes}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\ltimes$}}}

\begin{document}
$A\btimes B\ltimes C\utimes D$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the symbols also in subscripts or superscripts, then load also `amsmath` and do

```
\newcommand{\btimes}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\ltimes$}}}}
\newcommand{\utimes}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\ltimes$}}}}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with `\mathbin` in sub/superscripts. For example, `$A_\btimes B^\ltimes$` won't work without extra `{...}` brackets.

Comment: @MārisOzols You have to use `B^{\ltimes}`; there's nothing to do about that.

Answer (score 4):

according to

```
 texdoc symbols
```

table 50 the `mnsymbol` package has `\utimes` and `\dtimes`

table 51 the `mathdesign` package has `\utimes` and `\dtimes`