# How can I rotate \in by 90 degrees?

Tags: symbols, rotating

I am currently trying to show the domain of variables in a simple equation:

```
\[\begin{matrix}
    x & \cdot & W_{1,2} & = & o\\
    \in & & \in & & \in\\
    \mdr^{1\times n} & & \mdr^{n \times m} & & \mdr^{1 \times m}
\end{matrix}\]
```

[image]

There are some more issues with this way to show the domain of variables, but this question is mainly about the rotated `\in`.

### Failed tries

I've tried `\usepackage{rotating}`:

```
\[\begin{matrix}
    x & \cdot & W_{1,2} & = & o\\
    \text{\begin{rotate}{-90}$\in$\end{rotate}} & & \in & & \in\\
    \mdr^{1\times n} & & \mdr^{n \times m} & & \mdr^{1 \times m}
\end{matrix}
\]
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51109/commutative-diagram-with-elements

Comment: You can `\def\rin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\in$}}` and use `\rin` instead of `\in` in your formula. Requires package `graphicx`

Comment: Is this for a presentation with slides or for a paper?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The result is really ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}
\newcommand{\vin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\in$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{}}
x & \cdot & W_{1,2} & = & o \\
\vin && \vin && \vin \\
\mathbb{R}^{1\times n} && \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} && \mathbb{R}^{1\times m}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd simply avoid such visual description in print; I often use something like that on the blackboard, but it's a completely different situation. I'd prefer something like

```
\[
x\cdot W_{1,2} = o
\]
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ and $W_{1,2}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
```

in a printed document.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the `\usepackage{rotating}` package and use the `\begin{rotate}{30}...\end{rotate`} environment.

Or use the approach described in [Rotated $\ltimes$ symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73275/rotated-ltimes-symbol) (`\rotatebox` command from the `graphicx` package).

Comment: I've tried it and it looks ugly (see updated question)

Comment: `rotating` is not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea for annotating an equation without affecting the spacing and with a clean way of rotating the `\in`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\def\mdr{\mathbb{R}}

\tikzset{m/.style={inner sep=0, outer sep=0,remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
      $x_0\cdot A^n = o$
      \\[1em]
      $\tikz[m] \node (x) {$x_0$};\cdot \tikz[m] (a) \node {$A^n$}; = \tikz[m] \node (w) {$o$};$
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, node distance=.5]
        \node[shape=circle, draw=blue,minimum size=1.5em] (xc) at (x) {};
        \node[below=of x] (xd) {$\mdr^{1\times n}$};
        \path (xc) -- node[sloped] {$\in$} (xd);
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]