# How to rotate symbols in the equation environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, equations, symbols

I would like to make the following equation in the equation environment

[image]

However, I don't know how to insert the equality symbol that links both lines. Can this be done in the equation environment? If not, should we proceed?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: A similar question with accepted answers is available on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184576/how-can-i-rotate-in-by-90-degrees).

Comment: Unless this is a common notation, you might also look at \underbrace and \overbrace from the mathtools package.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely some very similar answer exists somewhere but I was not able to find it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \eqmakebox[pft]{$\widetilde{h\circ\partial+\partial\circ h}$}&=
 \widetilde{h\circ\partial}+\widetilde{\partial\circ h}=
 \widetilde{h}\circ\widetilde{\partial}+\widetilde{\partial}\circ\widetilde{h}\\
 \eqmakebox[pft][c]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$=$}}&\\
 \widetilde{(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}+(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}}&=
 \widetilde{(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}}+\widetilde{(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}}
 =(\bar\ell_1)^{\#}+(\bar\ell_1)^{\#}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with the really wide tilde from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101138/194703).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine,wasysym}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\AC}{.5150\wd0}}{.6\ht0}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \eqmakebox[pft]{$\reallywidetilde{h\circ\partial+\partial\circ h}$}&=
 \reallywidetilde{h\circ\partial}+\reallywidetilde{\partial\circ h}=
 \widetilde{h}\circ\widetilde{\partial}+\widetilde{\partial}\circ\widetilde{h}\\
 \eqmakebox[pft][c]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$=$}}&\\
 \reallywidetilde{(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}+(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}}&=
 \reallywidetilde{(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}}+\reallywidetilde{(\bar\ell_1)_{\#}}
 =(\bar\ell_1)^{\#}+(\bar\ell_1)^{\#}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future I would kindly like to ask you to show what you have tried such that others do not have to punch in the formulae from a screen shot.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way with `eqparbox` and `yhmath` (for `\widetilde`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox, graphicx} 

\newcommand*{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
  \eqmathbox{ \widetilde{h\circ \partial + \partial\circ h}} & = \widetilde{h\circ \partial} +\widetilde{ \partial\circ h} =\bar{\partial}\circ \widetilde{h}+ \widetilde{h}\circ\bar{\partial} \\[-1ex]
\eqmathbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$ = $}} \\[-0.5ex]
    \eqmathbox{\widetilde{(u_{1})_{\sharp}-(u_{0})_{\sharp}}} & = \widetilde{(u_{1})}_{\sharp}- \widetilde{(u_{0})}_{\sharp} = (i_{1})^{\sharp}- (i_{0})^{\sharp}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]