# Double line math sentence

Tags: math-mode

[image]

Hi, what's the best way to write this lines with that symbol between the rows

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Comment: Somewhat [symbols - How can I rotate \in by 90 degrees? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184576/how-can-i-rotate-in-by-90-degrees) but in the reverse direction.

Comment: This appears to be a commutative diagram, so using a package intended for that purpose would be appropriate.

Comment: No, it is not a commutative diagram (there is nothing that commutes here). I would in fact suggest to get rid of those vertical `\in`. It is understood that the (n,m) and n+m belongs to the sets indicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably use an array, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\upin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{95}{\(\in\)}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}c@{~}c@{~}c@{}}
\N \times \N & \rightarrow & \N \\
\upin & & \upin \\
(n,m) & \mapsto & n+m \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: array output]

I'm using `\rotatebox` from the graphicx package to rotate the symbols. I believe the stix package also defines an `\upin` command you could use directly.

The spacing with the upper right ℕ is not great, but I'm not sure there's a good way to solve that.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't specify what TeX format is expected. I can show you how to do this in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]
\def\N{{\bbchar N}}
\def\rotin{\rotbox{90}{$\in$}}
$$
  \matrix{
      \N \times \N & \longrightarrow & \N     \cr
        \rotin     &                 & \rotin \cr
       (n,m)       & \longmapsto     & n + m  \cr    
  }
$$
\bye
```

Comment: I always enjoy reading your non-LaTeX solutions, but I worry that a LaTeX beginner might develop bad habits (like using `$$...$$` instead of `\[...\]` or `\def` instead of `\newcommand`) because they don't realize that OpTeX is different from LaTeX. Just a thought.

Comment: IMHO, it is not true: each TeX beginner = LaTeX beginner. I know many examples they refutes this equality.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possibility with `tikz-cd`:

[image]

The `∈` symbols are labels on `phantom` arrows with the `sloped` option to follow the direction of the (invisible) arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsfonts}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\N\times\N\arrow[r] & \N\\
(n,m)\arrow[r, mapsto]\arrow[u, phantom, "\in", sloped] & n+m\arrow[u, phantom, "\in", sloped]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{4}
        \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}  && \rightarrow && \mathbb{N}\\
        \rotatebox{90}{$\epsilon$} && && \rotatebox{90}{$\epsilon$}\\
        (n,m) && \rightarrow && n+m
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `\rotatebox{90}{$\in$}`, not `\rotatebox{90}{$\epsilon$}`,

Comment: @ Mico You are correct.